# Examples of safecore being used in production (Optimism)

Tags: gnosis-safe

I was just wondering if anyone can point me to some examples of safecore being used in production on Optimism? Bonus if they are also using the Relay Kit. I want to make a decision between different wallet solutions and although I see a lot of hackathon projects, I am struggling to find anything that is live on mainnet using this. (not counting the standard gnosis safes)

Let me know if I need to add more context